# When two dice have been rolled, find probability that there will be $6$ on first die or on second die.

Tags: probability

Suppose  that we are asked following question :

> When two dice have been rolled, find probability that  there will be  $6$   on first  die or on second die.

let us denote  $E$  as a event that there will be $6$ on first dice, then probability will be

$P(E)=\frac{1}{6}$

let  $F$  denote event that there is  $6$ on   second  dice, so we have  again

$P(F)=\frac{1}{6}$

now we have following ones

$$P(E\text{ or }F)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}$$

but we know generally that

$P(A\text{ or } B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and }B)$
and  for mutual exclusive events  $P(A\text{ and } B)=0$

but for this  $P(A\text{ and }B)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$
so we would have

$$P(A\text{ or }B)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{36}=0.305555556$$

Which one is correct? In case of 
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}=0.333333333$$

Comment: As an aside, it is a pet peeve of mine when students of mine write equals signs for things which are not equalities.  $\frac{1}{3}\neq 0.333333333=\frac{333333333}{1000000000}$.  Similarly $\frac{11}{36}\neq 0.305555556=\frac{305555556}{1000000000}$.  Use `\approx` $\approx$ instead of `=`.  Equals signs should only be used for equality.

Comment: thanks  @JMoravitz i have also students  so we  are colleague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)-P(E\cap F)$

which is equal to $P(E)+P(F)$ if and only if $P(E\cap F)=0$

The correct answer is indeed $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$

Do not confuse the phrase "*mutually exclusive*" (*the intersection is empty and thus has probability zero*) with the phrase "*independent*" (*the probability of the intersection is the product of the probabilities*)

Comment: ahaa  that why i have posted  just  i was curious